# Unable to source an R script using in R markdown to use data frames in global environment

Tags: r-markdown

I am using R studio(Version 2023.09.0+463 (2023.09.0+463)). I have a R script "charting table.R" that I have created which is a pretty long code to transform data. I am trying to use  R markdown to create a report that contains both in line commands and tables. When I use the command source to use the above R script I get file "Error while opening file. No Such file or directory". When I list files the file appears in the directory. My goal is to use a prior R script in R markdown. Running the code works but "Knit"-ing it gives the error.

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
list.files()
file_path <- file.path("~", "Downloads", "Banner Cerner", "charting table.R")
source(file_path, local = knitr::knit_global())
```

Any help would be VERY appreciated

I have tried multiple combinations of the source() command